# OSMDroid bonuspack Custom Marker moving as I zoom out

Tags: position, zooming, osmdroid, markers

I have implemented OSMDroid and added a Custom Marker like this:

```
Marker marker = new Marker(mMapView);
marker.setPosition(getGeoPoint(item));
marker.setIcon(icon);
marker.setAnchor(Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, Marker.ANCHOR_BOTTOM);
marker.setTitle(item.getName());

if (mInfoWindow != null)
    marker.setInfoWindow(mInfoWindow);

if (mMapView != null) {
    mMapView.getOverlays().add(marker);
```

I use osmdroid bonus pack - org.osmdroid.bonuspack.overlays.Marker

This works well, as long as I dont zoom:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkmbY.png - good position

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRE9f.png - wrong position

The second problem with infoWindow position.
What I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really surprising. I assume the marker geoposition is at the manually drawn cross?

Could you provide your icon file?

And could you try with this icon:

[image: icon]

And this setting:

```
marker.setAnchor(Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER);
```

then provide the screen captures.

About InfoWindow position, describe the issue.

Comment: You are totally right - I have problem because my icon was wrong.
I change icon yesterday - now all is good.
Thank you for answer.

Comment: Btw maybe you know why I have leaked IntentReceiver

 ----- 
 Activity ru.sitesoft.turbur.activity.TabActivity has leaked IntentReceiver org.osmdroid.tileprovider.modules.MapTileFileStorageProviderBase$MyBroadcastReceiver@426c3be8 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
 ----- 

I don't know which receiver I need to unregister. I can't find good example for it.

Maybe it's because I use osmdroid MapView in ViewPager fragment?

Comment: For the IntentReceiver leak: you should create a dedicated question, provide related source code, and logcat traces. Also give the versions used (Android SDK, osmdroid).

Comment: Yes your algorithm is right but I thinked maybe it's popular problem. It isn't actual now because I fixed that problem.